# What is purpose of blank.html in js directory?

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, javascript, core

In Magento CE 1.7.0.2 in `js` directory there is file `blank.html`

What is purpose of this file exactly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's used by some Magento modules like Authorizenet as a fallback page for iframes. Other uses I have't found for it yet.

The actual URL will be set with javascript most likely, the blank html page is just to give it something to initially load.

Comment: Good info @Sander. got  learning from ur answer

Comment: I am not using Authorizenet module but still receiving traffic on the page. I just want to know, is there any known vulnerability issue related this file?

Comment: I'd probably say not but that depends on the amount of traffic. It shouldn't be insanely high. In the end, not a lot can be done with a blank html page